# Why are my string arrays incompatible with entries and entryValues attributes on RestrictionEntry of TYPE_CHOICE

Tags: android

I am attempting to set up managed configuration (referring to https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations#define-configuration), and I am getting the following errors on compilation.

```
AAPT: error: '@arrays/usage_display_values' is incompatible with attribute entries (attr) reference.
AAPT: error: '@arrays/usage_values' is incompatible with attribute entryValues (attr) reference.
```

Based on the documentation above for TYPE_CHOICE, and also the documentation for ListPreference (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference#attr_android:entries), I thought the following would work fine.

arrays.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="usage_display_values">
        <item>Personal</item>
        <item>Shared</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="usage_values">
        <item>personal</item>
        <item>shared</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

My restriction:

```
<restriction
        android:key="restrictionUsage"
        android:title="@string/client_usage_title"
        android:restrictionType="choice"
        android:entries="@arrays/usage_display_values"
        android:entryValues="@arrays/usage_values"
        android:description="@string/client_usage_desc"
        android:defaultValue="personal"
        />
```

Compare this to my list preference that I made for testing purposes, which compiles with no issues.

```
<ListPreference
        app:entryValues="@array/usage_values"
        app:entries="@array/usage_display_values"
        app:key="pref_usage"
        app:persistent="true"
        app:summary="@string/client_usage_desc"
        app:title="@string/client_usage_title"
        app:defaultValue="personal"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
        app:dependency="pref_override_mdm"/>
```

What is wrong with these string arrays when it comes to TYPE_CHOICE restrictions?

Comment: Typos. You've got `arrays` plural in the `<restriction>`'s values, instead of singular `array`; i.e., `"@arrays/usage_display_values"` should be `"@array/usage_display_values"`, and similarly for the other.

Comment: @MikeM Thanks. I wish the error could've said that the resource did not exist, rather than just "is incompatible". Would've been easier to spot!